# Fencing optimization question that seems to be underspecified

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

I just had a test question that asked the following (I wrote down the question verbatim):

> A rectangular lot is going to be built adjacent to a road. The fencing next to a road costs $15$ dollars per foot and $7$ dollars per foot otherwise. $3200$ feet of fencing will be used to enclose this lot. Determine the dimensions of the lot that will minimize the cost of building the fence.

I don't understand how this problem could ever be solved without specifying a minimum area required. Otherwise, I could have a minimum area of $0$ sqft and just place two $1600$ foot fences back to back to make the dimensions $1600$ by $0$ for a minimum cost of $22,400$ dollars.

I can guess how he wants me to solve the problem. Basically, $3$ sides of the fence will cost $7$ dollars per foot and one side will cost $15$ dollars per foot.

Now, if $3200$ was the square footage and **not** the perimeter, then I would solve for the more expensive side and create a formula like this.

Create a formula for the cost.

$$\begin{align*}
\textsf{Cost} &= 2\cdot 7\cdot L + 7\cdot W + 15\cdot W\\\\
\textsf{Cost} &= 14\cdot L + 7\cdot W + 15 W
\end{align*}$$

Solve for the width of the area.

$$\begin{align*}
3200 &= LW\\\\
W &= 3200/L
\end{align*}$$

I would then take that and plug it into my perimeter cost formula

$$\begin{align*}
\textsf{Cost}(L) &= 14L + 7(3200/L) + 15(3200/L)\\\\
\textsf{Cost}(L) &= 14L + 70400/L
\end{align*}$$

I would then plot this on a graphing calculator and find the minimum of the graph. In this case, the point would be $(70.9142, 1985.55)$,  $X$ is the width and $Y$ is the optimized minimum cost.

To find the length I simply just do undo the area.

$$\begin{align*}
3200 &= 70.9142 \cdot X \\\\
X &= 45.125
\end{align*}$$

This would make my optimized dimensions $70.9142$ feet by $45.125$ feet with a cost of $1985$ dollars.

Plugging this back in confirms the cost.

$$\textsf{Cost} = 14(70.9142) + 7(45.125) + 15(45.125) = 1985.55 \text{ dollars}$$

With all of that said. Can this problem be solved with the perimeter alone, or do I need a minimum area in order to figure it out? Your help in this matter is greatly appreciated because as is, this problem cannot be solved without either a minimum Length / Width or a specified Area or even a minimum Area.

EDIT: Spacing issues have been resolved for easier reading.

Comment: Certainly, your argument about the $1600\times 0$ fence is correct - that is the right answer to the problem as it was written. I've cleaned up the formatting a bit using MathJax - [please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Thank you for the guide link. I have never posted any questions to stackexhange before so I wasn't aware of how to format the math portion.